# bash script - can't get for loop working

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

**Background Info:**

I'm trying to follow the example posted here:  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/
I would like loop 9 times using a control variable called "i".

**Problem Description**

My code looks like this:

```
for i in {0..8..1}
do
  echo "i is $i"
  tmpdate=$(date -d "$i days" "+%b %d")
  echo $tmpdate
done
```

When I run this code, the debug prints show me:

```
                 "i is {0..8..1}"
```

instead of being a value between 0 and 8.

**What I've Checked So Far:**

I've tried to check my version of bash to make sure it supports this type of syntax.  I'm running version 4,2,25(1)

I also tried using C like syntax where you do for (i=0;i<=8;i++) but that doesn't work either.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I've also tried the following code:

```
for i in {0..8};
do
  echo "i is $i"
  tmpdate=$(date -d "$i days" "+%b %d")
  echo $tmpdate
done
```

And...

```
for i in {0..8}
do
  echo "i is $i"
  tmpdate=$(date -d "$i days" "+%b %d")
  echo $tmpdate
done
```

They all fail with the same results.

I also tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0;i<9;i++));
do
  echo "i is $i"
  tmpdate=$(date -d "$i days" "+%b %d")
  echo $tmpdate
done
```

And that gives me the error:

test.sh: 4: test.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

FYI.  I'm running on ubuntu 12

**EDIT 2**

Ok... so i think Weberick tipped me off to the issue... 
To execute the script, I was running "sh test.sh"
when in the code I had defined it as a BASH script!  My bad!

But here's the thing.  Ultimately, I need it to work in both bash and sh. 
so now that I'm being careful to make sure that I invoke the script the right way... I've noticed the following results:

1. when defined as a bash script and i execute using bash, the C-style version works!
2. when defined as an sh script and i execute using sh, the C-style version fails

   me@devbox:~/tmp/test$ sh test.sh 
   test.sh: 5: test.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
3. when defined as an sh script and i execute using sh the NON c style version ( aka for i in {n ..x}), I get the "i is {0..8}" output.

PS.  The ";" doesn't make a difference if you have the do on the next line...just FYI.

Comment: Your example works for me...

Comment: also I think you need a `;` like `for i in {0..8};`

Comment: how do you run the script? did you use 'bash myscript.sh' or added '#!/bin/bash'?

Comment: @weberik, please see edit 2

Comment: Also curious as to how the script is being run (ie are you doing `sh myscript.sh` or `./myscript.sh`? - Ubuntu's default shell is dash, which won't recognise some of this syntax)

Comment: thats what i suspected, you are not actually running bash at all. ubuntu probably created a link from /bin/bash to dash.

Comment: @weberik: It is `sh` that is symlinked to `dash` on Ubuntu (and we now know that the OP used `sh`) - `bash` is definitely NOT symlinked to `dash`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ubuntu's default shell is `dash`, which doesn't recognise either of the bashisms (brace expansion, C-style for loop) you tried. Try running your script using `bash` explicitly:

```
bash myscript.sh
```

or by setting the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`. Make sure NOT to run the script with `sh myscript.sh`.

dash should work if you use `seq`:

```
for i in $(seq 0 1 8); do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Just `{0..8}` should work in `bash`, the default increment is 1. If you want to use a C-style for loop in `bash`:

```
for ((i=0;i<9;i++)); do 
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for!  it works both ways using seq.  invoking via "bash test.sh" or "sh test.sh".  thanks.

Comment: 6 years late but this just helped me out, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm confident that

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0;i<9;i++))
do
  echo "i is $i"
  tmpdate=$(date -d "$i days" "+%b %d")
  echo $tmpdate
done
```

work on Ubuntu 12.04

If you still have an error, can you please try running

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

then

```
./test.sh
```

And the result is

```
i is 0
Apr 04
i is 1
Apr 05
i is 2
Apr 06
i is 3
Apr 07
i is 4
Apr 08
i is 5
Apr 09
i is 6
Apr 10
i is 7
Apr 11
i is 8
Apr 12
```

Answer (score 0):

The site you quote says

> Bash v4.0+ has inbuilt support for setting up a step value using {START..END..INCREMENT} syntax:

So you can just use `{0..8..1}` when you have a bash version greater than 4.0, which I guess is not the case (try `bash --version` in your terminal). Instead of `{0..8..1}` you can also use `{0..8}`.

If you have an older version you can use instead of `{START..END..INCREMENT}` the command `$(seq START INCREMENT END)` in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert at bash but according to [tdlp](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html) you need a `;` after the for statement.  There are many ways to to a range.  This is one of them.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for i in `seq 1 8`; do
        echo $i
    done
```